# ASUS Xonar DG not working Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, alsa

I've checked the "Questions that may already have your answer" to no avail.

Basically, there is no sound at all, the snd_oxygen drivers are all being loaded. I can see the sound card and all of it's separate ports in Settings->Sound->Output, but nothing is coming out. I tried adjusting the volume in alsamixer, but for some reason the volume won't change (all that is there are some options [Speakers, Headphones, FP Headphones] and they change when I press the up/down arrow keys) at all.

I have also tried many other terminal commands, such as reloading alsa and checking if the sound card is even being detected, which it is.

I'm left clueless. It says on a bug report that this has been unassigned for over a year. Surely that's not right.

Thanks in advance, Caelan.

Comment: OK, SO I've just realised that sound words from the back port, in which it did not yesterday (kind of strange, although I did do an update and noticed it had updated ALSA).

Answer (score 2):

I just had to change the Analog Output in Alsamixer to Multichannel for the rear panel output to work.

Seen here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2261950

Answer (score 1):

That driver [is incomplete](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix%3aVendor-Asus):

> This hardware has no volume controls; use PulseAudio.
>   Front panel, HP, and microphones do not work.

You must use the line output at the back of the card, or the digital output.

Comment: Is it possible to request them to complete it? There are a fair few threads strewn around the net from people that have had this problem.

Comment: The problem is lack of developer time ...

Answer (score 1):

I have this same card and just did some digging around to get my front panel audio working.

Full support for this card has been added to alsa [as described here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/919809)

I can confirm that kernel 3.13 works with this card.  (Which for me is Mint 16 Cinnamon, but is also included in Ubuntu 14.04).